# How could i do a configuration system for my Lua extensions?

Tags: c, plugins, lua

I added lua scripting support for my C software to allow for easier extension and addition of new features.

For example, I look for .lua files inside a folder. Those plugins contain functions to identify to my software, like:

```
function GetName()
    return "Youtube Search"
end
```

It have too the "Workers functions" for example:

```
function Search(strTerm, SearchResult)
     --SEACH YOUTUBE
     SearchResult = MYRESULTS    
end
```

This way, my software now can search on youtube thanks to this plugin.

But now I have a problem, I cannot find a suitable solution to it. Some plugins require a configuration system, for example in this Youtube plugin it needs a property that only return WebM videos. But a liveLeak plugin don´t need this property.

In the my Application it should be capable of parsing what the plugin need (2 integers and 1 string) and then displaying it in a list.

How could I elegantly implement a solution that fix those issues?

Answer (score 2):

How about a pair of functions (optionally) exposed by plugins like `getSupportedConfigItems()` and `setConfigItems(tbl)`?  If I'm understanding your question correctly (and I must admit, the "2 integers and 1 string" part I do not understand), it could look like this for the YouTube plugin:

```
function getSupportedConfigItems()
    return {
        showWebMOnly = {
            type = 'boolean',
            description = 'Show only WebM videos',
            default = true
        }
    }
end

function setConfigItems(tbl)
    for key, value in pairs(tbl) do
        if key == 'showWebMOnly' then
            -- ...
        end
    end
end
```

This way your application could be written to support showing preferences for a few well-known types (defined by you, the example being a boolean).  The application would ask each plugin what preferences it can support, and display options for those.  It would then tell the plugin which options were selected, and what their values are.

Comment: That exactly what i looking for !
But i don´t known these structures. Could you explain it ? What the type that getSupportedConfigItems returns ? How could specify more than one ? How could i bind this to c ?

Comment: It just returns a table. So you decide what variables you would like to have in it, and as don here, add their type, description and default value. It's all really free-form, no fixed format.

Comment: The way I wrote it, the get method just returns a table.  You could easily add second, third, and so on items for however many preferences your plugin has (the app would show them as a list of zero or more preferences per plugin).